# Should I use multiple inheritance to implement search tree with linked list?

Tags: c++, tree, linked-list, multiple-inheritance

I have a `List` class and an AVL `Tree` class, and I want to create a class that is essentially an AVL tree with the added option of traversing the elements in ascending order:

```
            _5_
          _/   \_
         3       8
        / \     / \
       2   4   7   9

       2,3,4,5,7,8,9
```

The point being, I want to be able to insert/remove etc. in `O(log(n))` time, but I also want to go from `4` to `5` in `O(1)` time.

Should I create a new class using MI?

```
class ListTree: private List, public Tree
```

If so, what should I worry about? If not, why not?

Comment: Would it be bad to maintain both a list and a tree of the same data? Composition of data should be preferred over inheritance because it minimizes how tightly coupled the classes will be, and allows for greater flexibility.

Comment: @YoungJohn Both the Tree and the List don't allow direct access to the addresses of the nodes. Say I search for `4` in the Tree part, how do I link to the `4` in the List?

Comment: Don't you just want to add a List interface to your AVL tree? That is, if you want to walk the list from first to last entry, you are just traversing the tree?

Comment: @StarPilot The other way round: I want to keep my Tree interface (the user won't know it's a list). Also, traversing the tree isn't the same as traversing the list... to get from `4` to `5` is O(1) in the list but O(log(n)) in the tree, and inserting a new entry while keeping the data in ascending order is O(n) in a list but O(log(n)) in the tree

Comment: Use a SkipList, and tag on the Tree interface to it. With a skip list, you have the bottom layer's "next node -> next node -> next node -> next node" but you also have the tree's quick search thanks to the multi-layer approach of the SkipList. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

Comment: @StarPilot Thanks, but this is a Uni project and skip lists don't meet the worst case complexity requirements... If this was the real world you'd probably by right :)

Comment: If you are AT 4 in a skip list, then it is just O(1) to get to the next node (thanks to the next link of the node). If it is random look up, you can use an indexed skip list to keep random look up times to O(log n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple inheritance is a good candidate if your new class has an "**is a**" relationship with all the base classes your envisage.

**Is it a tree ?**

> I want to create a class that is essentially an AVL tree with the
>   added option of ...

According to this statement, your `ListTree` definitively  **is a** `Tree` and should inherit from it.

**Is it a list ?**

Well it depends of what's behind your `List` !  If it's a pure virtual class that only defines an interface which needs to be derived in concrete list classes, then **yes**:  your `ListTree` is a list from the astraction point of view.

But if your `List` is already a concrete class, --which I asusme here-- then the answer should be **NO**.  Why ?  a list is flat an a tree is not.  The fact that a tree can be traversed **like a** list doesn't make it a list.

If you would then opt for MI, you'd inherit internal data of both `Tree` AND `List`.  For each operation like inserting and removing you'd have to synchronize both structures in a consistent way.  If you'd just delegate insertion to both base classes for example, you'd be at O(n) instead of O(log(n)).

**How to do then ?**

It's difficult to give further advice without knowing how you manage the container elements.

What about adding a `List` member to your `ListTree` class (composition instead of inheritance), and storing in your tree references/pointers to the list nodes ?

For traversal you'd use the list in O(1). For removing/inserting, you use the tree to find the node where to insert or to remove in O(log(n)), perform the operation on the list node (provided that the list is double linked), and knowing that balancing is without effect on the order of the nodes in the list.